# Changes in the header colour of Facebook Like Box

Tags: facebook, plugins, drupal

We have seen there have been some changes in the header colour of the [Like Box social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/):

Anybody knows if it is planned to offer a parameter to set that colour using the API (as with the border colour)?. We are using the API in a module [fb_likebox](http://drupal.org/project/fb_likebox/) for the free software CMS Drupal, and we were wondering what the best way to override this setting will be. We were thinking in adding it as a configurable setting, but if not we will try from a front-end (overriding the CSS) point of view.

Answer (score 0):

define a class, named 'fbConnectWidgetHeaderTitleBranded', within the file where you add this fb api 
And you can define your custom CSS. This class is used by Fb to its Header.

This CSS is used by fb:
background : "none repeat scroll 0 0 #3B5998".